# ArcGIS JS API Pop-Up w/TabContainer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

I am attemtping to call a dojo tab container within an ESRI pop-up. The code that I have (see below) is able to create a pop-up with a tab container and the contents, but also creates three 'dead' dropdown menus. Is there a way to create the pop-up without the dropdown menus?

```
  var map;
  var resizeTimer;
  var identifyTask,identifyParams;

  function init() {        
    //setup the popup window 
    var popup = new esri.dijit.Popup({
      fillSymbol: new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2), new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.25]))
    }, dojo.create("div"));

    map = new esri.Map("map",{
      infoWindow:popup,
    });


    dojo.connect(map,"onLoad",mapReady);

    //Add the imagery layer to the map. View the ArcGIS Online site for services http://arcgisonline/home/search.html?t=content&f=typekeywords:service    
    var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer");
    map.addLayer(basemap);

    var landBaseLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://<someServer>/ArcGIS/rest/services/test/MapServer");
    map.addLayer(landBaseLayer)
  }

      function mapReady(map){

       dojo.connect(map,"onClick",executeIdentifyTask);

       //create identify tasks and setup parameters 
       identifyTask = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("http://<someServer>/ArcGIS/rest/services/test/MapServer");

       identifyParams = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
       identifyParams.tolerance = 3;
       identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
       identifyParams.layerIds = [0];
       identifyParams.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
       identifyParams.width  = map.width;
       identifyParams.height = map.height;


       //resize the map when the browser resizes
       dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', map,map.resize);

      }

       function executeIdentifyTask(evt) {
            identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
            identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
    var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);

    deferred.addCallback(function(response) {     
      // response is an array of identify result objects    
      // Let's return an array of features.
      return dojo.map(response, function(result) {
        var feature = result.feature;
        feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
        console.log(feature.attributes.OBJECTID);
        var template = new esri.InfoTemplate();
        template.setTitle("</b>Hello World</b>");
        template.setContent(getWindowContent);
        feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        return feature;
      });
    });


    // InfoWindow expects an array of features from each deferred
    // object that you pass. If the response from the task execution 
    // above is not an array of features, then you need to add a callback
    // like the one above to post-process the response and return an
    // array of features.
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures([ deferred ]);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
  }

  function getWindowContent(graphic) {
    //make a tab container 
    var tc = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
    });

    return tc.domNode;
  }

  dojo.addOnLoad(init);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears changing the TabContainer code to the following will fix the issue:

```
var tc = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
            style: "width:100%;height:100%;",
            useMenu: false,
            useSlider: false,
        }, dojo.create('div'));
```